# Teaching Online at US Universities without a proof of authorization to work in the United States

Tags: application, job-search, united-states, online-learning, anthropology

Good morning,
My name is Gretel Echazú, I am an Argentinian anthropologist who researched in Brazil, Argentina and Peru. I got my PhD in anthropology with an investigation linked to health, race and gender issues in the Peruvian Amazon. I have a Post-Doctoral scholarship at a Federal University here in Natal, Northeastern Brazil. I´ve thought online once, for a plataform linked to ethnobotany. To make my work experience wider, I would love to start teaching online as an adjunct professor. I see that the majority of job offers come from US institutions that ask for "proof of authorization" to work in the US. I wander if it is possible for me to teach online from Brazil to create materials for institutions that are in the US.
Same question would go for European academic settings.
Thank you very much.
Gretel

Comment: Your best chance might be to find a U.S. or European institution with a campus in Argentina.  That way, you could be hired (and paid) in Argentina while teaching students elsewhere.

Comment: This is probably a better fit at expats.se because it is about working internationally and what permits are required. If you flag it I will be happy to move it.

Answer (score 3):

If the job advertisement mentions that proof of authorization to work in the US is required, that means you should obtain a visa to work in the United States before you apply for the job.  Your application will probably not be read if you do not have the visa and are not a US citizen.

It is not worth obtaining the visa to teach one course.